# Cartoon with a young unicorn and a demon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, demons, unicorns

In the late 80s or early 90s I remember watching an animated series that followed a young unicorn and a demon.

In one episode the unicorn gave the demon his horn, and the unicorn almost died.

In another episode there was a man who was able to turn people into human shaped building blocks and built a huge tower from them.

Those are the two scenes I remember with any clarity.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: The Fantastic Adventures of Unico (1981) - Movie Poster] [image: Unico in the Island of Magic (1983) - Movie Poster]

You're looking for the animated films featuring ["**Unico**"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unico) :-)

> Unico is a baby unicorn with white fur, a pink mane, and little
>   cinnamon bun-shaped ears, who was born with the very special gift of
>   making all living creatures lighthearted and happy. His friends
>   include Beezle, the young Devil of Solitude; Chao ("Katy"), a naive
>   little kitty who longs to be a human girl, and to learn magic from a
>   real witch; a spunky little Sphinx, and a warm-hearted human girl
>   named Cheri.

[**The Fantastic Adventures of Unico** (1981)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083258/)

[image: Unico - Pic 01]

This is the film where he loses or rather gives away his horn and gets into big trouble....

> [Unico] agrees to hand over his horn to Beezle if he promises to be
>   Best Friends Forever. With Unico's horn now part of him Beezle becomes
>   even more 'spirited' (unbearable) and chases Unico around the island
>   and eventually off a cliff, into the sea. Without his horn Unico is
>   powerless and begins to drown...

[**Unico in the Island of Magic** (1983)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086515/)

[image: Unico - Pic 02]

This is the one with the castle made up of human building blocks....

> Lord Kuruku plans to turn all living creatures, animals and people
>   alike, into zombie-like beings called "Living Puppets" [these are the
>   scary human building blocks in the movie] to be his slaves. Toby
>   [Cheri's brother] works for Lord Kuruku, his job is to change people
>   into Living Puppets and then lure them to Kuruku's island castle in
>   exchange for learning more of Kuruku's magic.

<sup>*~ Edited from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unico) and [AnimeGames](http://www.anime-games.co.uk/VHS/anime/unico-fantastic-adventures.php)*</sup>

Comment: Thank you so very much! I really appreciate that you included pictures!

Comment: Now *that's* a thorough answer!