# Anime about people turning into square-like, stone robots

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking for a movie I saw when I was younger. I've been trying to find it for years. I'm for sure that it was anime I'm just unsure as to whether it was a tv show or movie. It seemed like a movie.

I know there were 2 siblings a boy and a girl. I believe from what I can remember the brother was older. One of the two, I believe it was the brother was in league with the evil power of the movie I think. The only part I can remember these people were being turned into what I think was stone-maybe robots. They were very square looking at least in my memory-like they would be lego pieces that would fit together to make this large structure. I'm unsure if it was a ship, or a castle, but it was raising up into the sky. I have tried to look at movies online from google and IMDB and thus far have come up empty. I'm almost positive I saw it in the early 90s maybe late 80s. I think the evil power was some kind of witch. I want to say it was a woman but I'm not for sure. I don't remember seeing the evil power but I think I can vaguely remember the sibling being upset with "her" that this would happen to his sister or something of that nature.

Comment: I remember the movie the OP is speaking of, but it's not Unico in the Island of Magic. This movie was about a sister who's older brother went off and had learned magic. I remember him wearing some sort of blue cloak with a pointed blue felt hat. I remember watching the movie back in 1987-1988 on television. The girl lived with her parents in the woods I believe and the brother had returned. The person who taught the older brother magic had followed him or something, and the brother defended his sister and the two fought.

Answer (score 9):

Possibly ''[Unico in the Island of Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unico#Unico_in_the_Island_of_Magic)'':

> In this film, Unico meets a kind-hearted young girl named Cheri (also spelled "Cherry", voiced by Sumi Shimamoto). Cheri's older brother, Toby (in Japanese, "Torubi", voiced by Shuichi Ikeda), is working for the evil Lord Kuruku (in Japanese, "Kukuruku"), who plans to turn all living creatures, animals and people alike, into unusual zombie-like beings called "Living Puppets" to be his slaves; Toby's job is to change people into Living Puppets and then lure the Living Puppets to Kuruku's island castle in exchange for learning more of Kuruku's magic. His plan is to obey and serve until he learns enough to be the master, but fails to protect Cheri twice. Toby also takes on Melvin the Magnificat ("Yamaneko" in Japanese) - who hates Unico because Unico "intruded" in "his" forest (the forest in which the West Wind left Unico) - as his assistant. After Cheri's parents and neighbors all get turned into Living Puppets, she and Unico team up to stop Kuruku.

The Living Puppets:
[image: Living Puppets]

As walls:
[image]

Comment: If so, it's a Duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/49800/23243 as well as a few other times this anime has come up :)

Comment: I don't know who dreamt up this movie bit it was terrifying to me as a child. Like...what were they thinking?!